# Scene reconstruction after dense SIFT

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, sift, 3d-reconstruction

I am using `vl_dsift` in MATLAB to compute dense SIFT features in a pair of stereo images. The feature correspondences seem to be correct more or less, but when I triangulate my 3D cloud is flat, that is all points have the same depth, which is not true for my scene and also does not happen when I use `vl_sift`. 
My code is as follows:

```
[fL, dL] = vl_dsift(frameLeftGray,'step',10,'size',20,'fast') ;
[fR, dR] = vl_dsift(frameRightGray,'step',10,'size',20,'fast') ;

[matches, scores] = vl_ubcmatch(dL, dR, 1.5) ;

matchedPoints1 = fL(1:2,matches(1,:))';
matchedPoints2 = fR(1:2,matches(2,:))';

points3D = triangulate(matchedPoints1, matchedPoints2,stereoParams);

points3D = points3D ./ 1000;


numPixels = size(frameLeftRect, 1) * size(frameLeftRect, 2);
allColors = reshape(frameLeftRect, [numPixels, 3]);
colorIdx = sub2ind([size(frameLeftRect, 1), size(frameLeftRect, 2)],round(matchedPoints1(:,2)), round(matchedPoints1(:, 1)));
color = allColors(colorIdx, :);

ptCloud1 = pointCloud(points3D, 'Color', color);

player3D = pcplayer([-0.02, 0.02], [-0.05, 0.05], [0.02, 0.12], 'VerticalAxis', 'y', 'VerticalAxisDir', 'up');

view(player3D, ptCloud1);
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?

[image: feature matches]

[image: scene after vl_dsift]

If I use vl_sift instead and keep everything else the same

```
[fL, dL] = vl_sift(frameLeftGray,'levels',10) ;
[fR, dR] = vl_sift(frameRightGray,'levels',10) ;
```

then, I get the following scene, whose shape I know is more accurate:
[image: scene after vl_sift]

Comment: It seems that for 3D points, the `triangulation` function requires either 2 or 4 arguments. Here you are passing 3 arguments, so a 2D triangulation is performed. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation-class.html

Comment: @Eskapp I am using `triangulate`, not `triangulation`

Comment: ooops, my bad I read your question too fast! When you say that it works using `vl_sift`, is it the only modification you bring to your code?
It would be useful to see both codes and output.

Comment: @Eskapp I updated my question.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you sure it is not a weird rendering effect from Matlab? Because I honestly see no reason why changing the sampling method would so drastically change the results... I might not be able to help you though I am pretty used to work with SIFT features but not with this API :(

Comment: @Eskapp I don't know... It seems weird indeed :\

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever compute the distance between any pair dsift features? The reason why the point cloud is flat is because the disparity between the corresponding features are the same.